# How to display popup box in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, popup

I'm trying to use 'popups' module . But it is throwing the following error.

```
   appendLocation: (document.body || document.documentElement),
                     ^

   ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Comment: Hey was wondering did you find any solution? If you did then it would be nice to post it ;)

Comment: @Diksha I didnt find solution to this.I have avoided the popups.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work since NodeJS runs on server side and you do not have the **document** object on the server side. You cannot do it directly, you will have to send a response to the client side of some sort and then use the popups package.

Comment: However, the error shows up when you try to include the npm module.  I have the same problem.  I can't include `popupS`, let alone use it anywhere in my code.